# Creating simple Node server with Kotlin

Tags: javascript, node.js, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

I'm trying to create a simple Node server using Kotlin to replicate the basic sample [here](https://nodejs.org/en/about/):

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

So, I did the below:

Created new folder, named it `node`

Create `npm package` using `npm init`

Created new `gradle project` using this command: `gradle init --type java-library`

Deleted the `src/main` and the `src/test` folders

Created the `src/kotlin` and `src/resources` folders

Replaced the content of the `build.gradle` file by:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    ext.node_dir = 'node'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" 
    }
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin2js'

repositories {     jcenter()    }

dependencies {
    def kotlinx_html_version = "0.6.8"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
}

sourceSets.main {
   kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/kotlin'
   resources.srcDirs += 'src/resources'
}

compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
   outputFile = "${projectDir}/${node_dir}/index.js"
   moduleKind = "commonjs" 
   sourceMap = true
}

clean.doFirst() {
    delete("${node_dir}")
}
```

Installed `kotlin` from `npm` as local version: `npm i kotlin`
Note: installing it globally `npm i -g kotlin` did not work at all.

Note: I did it also using `npm install` or `npm i` after adding the dependencies to the `package.json` file, which became like:

```
{
  "name": "kotlin-node-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node Application built with Kotlin Lang",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "kotlin": "^1.2.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "kotlin"
  ],
  "author": "Hasan Yousef",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Created my file at `src/kotlin/Main.Kt` as below:

```
external fun require(module:String):dynamic

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello JavaScript!")

    val http = require("http")
    val hostname = "127.0.0.1"
    val port = 3000

    println("Server will try to run at http://${hostname}:${port}/")

    val server = http.createServer{req, res -> 
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        res.end("Hello World\n")
    }

    server.listen{port, hostname ->
       println("Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/")
    }
}
```

Built the project using `gradle build` and got the `index.js` file generated as required.

Once running the file `node index.js` it did not work, and looks the app not reading the values of `port` and `host` upon calling the `server.listen`.

The structure, code and output of the app are in this screenshot:

[image]

The `index.js` generated is:

```
(function (_, Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var println = Kotlin.kotlin.io.println_s8jyv4$;
  var Unit = Kotlin.kotlin.Unit;
  function main$lambda(req, res) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    return res.end('Hello World\n');
  }
  function main$lambda_0(port, hostname) {
    println('Server running at http://' + hostname + ':' + port + '/');
    return Unit;
  }
  function main(args) {
    println('Hello JavaScript!');
    var http = require('http');
    var hostname = '127.0.0.1';
    var port = 3000;
    println('Server will try to run at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
    var server = http.createServer(main$lambda);
    server.listen(main$lambda_0);
  }
  _.main_kand9s$ = main;
  main([]);
  Kotlin.defineModule('index', _);
  return _;
}(module.exports, require('kotlin')));

//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found it, it is in calling `server.listen`

Considering the syntax as 'server.listen(port, hostname, backlog, callback);'

In `Kotlin` it should be:

```
server.listen(port, hostname, fun() { 
    println("Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/")
})
```

So, the below code worked perfectly with me now:

```
external fun require(module:String):dynamic

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello JavaScript!")

    val http = require("http")
    val hostname = "127.0.0.1"
    val port = 3000

    println("Server will try to run at http://${hostname}:${port}/")

    val server = http.createServer{req, res -> 
        res.statusCode = 200
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        res.end("Hello World\n")
    }

    server.listen(port, hostname, fun() { 
        println("Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/")
    })

    /* OR
    server.listen(port, hostname, {
       println("Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/") } )
    */

   /* OR
    server.listen(port, hostname) {
      println("Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/") }
   */
}
```

And the generated compiled `index.js` file is:

```
(function (_, Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var println = Kotlin.kotlin.io.println_s8jyv4$;
  function main$lambda(req, res) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    return res.end('Hello World\n');
  }
  function main$lambda_0() {
    println('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3030/');
  }
  function main(args) {
    println('Hello JavaScript!');
    var http = require('http');
    var hostname = '127.0.0.1';
    var port = 3030;
    println('Server will try to run at http://127.0.0.1:3030/');
    var server = http.createServer(main$lambda);
    server.listen(port, hostname, main$lambda_0);
  }
  _.main_kand9s$ = main;
  main([]);
  Kotlin.defineModule('index', _);
  return _;
}(module.exports, require('kotlin')));

//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Then I run it smoothly using `node node/index.js` command